# What does it mean that a core supports 2 threads?

Tags: computer-architecture, concurrency, threads

I understand that a process may have multiple threads, and that a processor may have multiple cores to run processes in parallel.

But I can't understand how a core may allow multiple threads, what does it change from a core with one thread support?

Answer (score 3):

See Wikipedia on [Computer Multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking) and [Time-sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-sharing), which have an explanation of how operating systems allow this.  Basically, they switch between multiple threads.

Read also about [hardware multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_%28computer_architecture%29).  This allows a single core to execute multiple threads *concurrently*, without switching between them.

Comment: Thanks! After your answer I search in books for more information aiming to hardware multithreading and I understood

Answer (score 0):

Any core "can" work on a multitude of processes or threads - you can have multithreading on single core machines (or more threads than cores in general).

The expensive part with threads is *context switching* - saving and restoring the set of (nowadays rather large) registers when switching to a different thread. If a core is advertised as "supporting *two* threads" (in opposite to "*n* threads"), one might guess it has either capabilities for hardware threading, but, more likely, ist just has an extra register bank.